# How to find color of a certain pixel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I need to find the color of a certain pixel WITHIN my JFrame. Unfortunately, I want the frame to be movable, so I can't use the Robot method createScreenCapture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `JFrame.getLocationOnScreen()` method to get the frames location.

Then you use the `Robot.getPixelColor(...)` method to get the pixel relative to the frames location.

Comment: Thank you so much!